# repeat div and UL 3 times but li will repeat 7 times

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, repeat

I have a HTML structure with bootstrap 3 columns, which all `div` repeat 3 times only, but all `div` have one `ul` and each ul has 7 `li`.

I want to show the dynamic list according to the below HTML structure:

```
<div class="col-md-4 padding-left">
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Mechanical Engineering Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> BPO Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Networking  Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Java Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Online Marketing Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Animation  Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Design Engineer Jobs</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 padding-left">
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Analytics Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> UI/UX Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> NLP Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Marketing Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Banking Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> MBA Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Teaching Jobs</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 padding-left">
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Accounting Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Retail Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Travel Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Merchandiser Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Architecture  Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Banking Insurance Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Music Jobs</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For this I have seen the below answers and tried with the below code.

I have tried with the below code but it's not working as is should.

```
<?php
    $sqlEng = mysql_query('select * from jobs_category');
    $count = 1;
    while($resEng = mysql_fetch_array($sqlEng)){
      if ($count%3 == 1)
        {  
?>
    <div class="col-md-4 padding-left">

    <?php } ?>
    <ul class="unstyled">   

    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <?php echo $resEng['name'];?></a></li>

    </ul>
  <?php if ($count%3 == 0)
    {
  ?>        
</div>
<?php } $count++; } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and inspecting the vars at each step?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to print the count in each repeat.

Comment: And you observed ...?

Comment: @philipxy Yes, I have observed the count, but the UL and Li is not repeating correctly

Comment: That is a vague summary of what you observed. *Of course* it "is not repeating correctly"--whatever that is summarizing. Tell us exactly what you observed! Please read & act on [mcve]. Please read about SO code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have only 21 records in the table.

try this.

```
    <?php
    //$sqlEng = mysql_query('select * from jobs_category');
    $servername = "localhost:3306";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "stack1");

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $sqlEng = $conn->query('select * from jobs_category');
    $count = 1;

    while($resEng = $sqlEng->fetch_assoc()){

      if ($count%7 == 1)
        { 
?>
<div class="col-md-4 padding-left">
<ul class="unstyled"> 
<?php   } ?>



<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <?php  echo $resEng['name'];?></a></li>



<?php if ($count%7 == 0)
        {
  ?> 
</ul>  
</div>
<?php   } $count++;     

    } ?>
```

tested in my local.

Comment: This is not correct, it's repeating `ul` 7 times in each `div`, instead of each `div` has repeat only 7 `li` within one `ul`.

Comment: @mageDev0688 i edited answer after posting this the first time. Sure you got the latest one?

Comment: It's again same issue if you can run this program and see the output.

Comment: @mageDev0688 updated the code after testing in local. check now.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you are trying to spread the list items `<li> A Job </li>` across three lists `<div> <ul> List Items </ul> </div>`

```
<?php
$sqlEng = mysql_query('select * from jobs_category');
$count = 1;
$group_one = "
<div class='col-md-4 padding-left'>
<ul class='unstyled'>

";
$group_two = "
<div class='col-md-4 padding-left'>
<ul class='unstyled'>

";
$group_three = "
<div class='col-md-4 padding-left'>
<ul class='unstyled'>

";

while($resEng = mysql_fetch_array($sqlEng)){
    if($count > 3) {
        $count = 1;
    }
    switch ($count) {
        case 1:
        $group_one .= "
        <li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i> " .$resEng['name'] . "</a></li>";
        break;
        case 2:
        $group_two .= "
        <li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i> " .$resEng['name'] . "</a></li>";
        break;
        case 3:
        $group_three .= "
        <li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i> " .$resEng['name'] . "</a></li>";

    }
    $count++;

}

$group_one .= "
</ul>
</div>";
$group_two .= "
</ul>
</div>";
$group_three .= "
</ul>
</div>";

echo $group_one . $group_two . $group_three;
?>
```

You want to consider using MySQl improved `mysqli` https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp